# AdWords API PHP OAuth2 Web Flow

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

***Update: This does actually refresh Oauth2 tokens. I had an error in my code that was causing it to fail. In the hopes that this helps someone else I have decided to not delete it***

I'm running into problems with regenerating oauth2tokens using a refresh token in the AdWords API (v201702). Using the code sample found [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/wiki/API-access-on-behalf-of-your-clients-(web-flow)), I'm able to authenticate users after they grant access but I can't figure out how to generate a new oauth2token using the refresh token once the original token has expired. The only way I can make requests to the API is with constant reauthentication. This is the code I have right now:

```
$oauth2Token = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
 ->withClientId($clientId)
 ->withClientSecret($clientSecret)
 ->withRefreshToken($refreshToken)
 ->build();
$adWordsSession = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
 ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2Token)
 ->withDeveloperToken($developerToken)
 ->build();
```

When I try to use that adWordsSession to make API calls, I get a bad request. The $oauth2Token doesn't contain an accessToken so I'm assuming it's not properly generating. Can anyone help?